# Javascript getfile rather than php

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send forms using XHR as key/value pairs

I have stumbled across this [blog](http://robertnyman.com/2013/02/11/using-formdata-to-send-forms-with-xhr-as-keyvalue-pairs/):

However, I do not want to use PHP. Is anyone familiar how to do this with Javascript? Specifically how to read out the form on the server?

In other words how do I convert the following into a Javascript file?

```
<?php
    $fileName = $_FILES['blobbie']['name'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['blobbie']['type'];
    $fileContent = file_get_contents($_FILES['blobbie']['tmp_name']);
    $dataURL='data:'.$fileType.';base64,'.base64_encode($fileContent);
    echo $dataURL;
?>
```

Comment: Easy peasy, you install Node.js

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you're just doing a simple operation and the server doesn't need the file, you can just handle everything with JavaScript on the client end.

```js
document.getElementById("filePicker").addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(readerEvt) {
    document.getElementById("base64").value = btoa(readerEvt.target.result);
  };
  reader.readAsBinaryString(evt.target.files[0]);
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="filePicker"><br><br>
<textarea id="base64" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
```